# Encrypted To-Do app?

Tags: encryption, synchronization, todo

Looking for a To-Do app recommendation with following capabilities:

1. Encrypted (at rest).
2. Open-source.
3. Mobile app.
4. Web app or Windows desktop app.
5. File attachment.
6. Free basic version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Keepass.

https://keepass.info/download.html

1. Encrypted with AES (customizable)
2. [2.42.1 source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%202.x/2.42.1/KeePass-2.42.1-Source.zip/download)
3. See download page (available on Android, iPhone/iPad)
4. See download page (available as web app, and on Windows, MacOS, Linux)
5. Yes (add attachment in the extra details section)
6. It is completely free and open source

The title of the "to-do" can be added in as the title or username section. The actual "to-do" can be added in the details section of a password entry.